# Recurring calender invitation was showing one hour off after DST starts

Tags: outlook, sendmail, icalendar, dst, vcalendar

I am sending a request from my .net application(C#) to create recurring meeting invite in outlook.
the meeting invite was showing one hour off during day light saving (march 8th 2015 to 1st nov 2015).

remaining time, my calender shows correct time and i am sending below code to outlook calender.

Please note my application source using EST and destination to all the time zones.

code for the same.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Schedule a Meeting
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20150221T120000Z
DTEND:20150221T123000Z
LOCATION:XYZ, ABC
UID:0c5c9c55-851f-462b-bdf2-48df5991561b
DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:Test for UTC Time Zone
SUMMARY:Test for UTC Time Zone
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:myapplication@gmail.com
ATTENDEE;CN=&quot;&quot;;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:sender@gmail.com.com
RRULE:FREQ=Monthly;COUNT=4;BYDAY=3SA
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Please show what the invitation looks like, and tell us what Outlook thinks your time zone is. I suspect the problem is that you've specified the wrong time zone.

Comment: Please see the edit version with the screens

Comment: That hasn't shown what the ical information looks like. I was asking for the text of the invitation that you're attaching... Note how Outlook explicitly tells you that the invitation specifies UTC...

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
DTSTART: starttime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd\\THHmmss\\Z")
DTEND: Endtime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd\\THHmmss\\Z")
```

You're explicitly specifying the start and end times as UTC, and you're never specifying the time zone.

If you want an event to be *in* a time zone, you should specify the local time instead of a UTC time (so no Z at the end) and a `TZID` property to specify the time zone. I suggest you export some of your existing events as ical entries to see what those look like.

You can leave the value without any time zone if you want it to be a "floating time" which will be interpreted in whatever the local time zone is.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but i need to send an invitations to difference time zones, please let us know how i can set DTzone as local

Comment: @Ddev: I've edited my answer - you can skip a time zone specification entirely if you want, but you need to remove the `Z`... and remove the `ToUniversalTime` call too.

Comment: I have tried with TZID and also by removing Z and ToUniversalTIme but still invite was sending with different time. for your info, single reservation is working and i have the issue with only recurring reservations

Comment: @Ddev: Well "with different time" doesn't really tell us much. You should have a look at the text you're sending and how it appears in Outlook. If you send it with the right local time and no TZID or Z, it should be floating.

Comment: Hi  Jon, I have updated my Question with more relevant and be specific. Please let me know if this one helps.